# Disable Cached Exchange Mode in GPO for Outlook 2016 with the option to enable it (not grayed out)

Tags: windows-registry, group-policy, microsoft-outlook-2016, exchange-2013

There seems to be no granular policy in the Office 2016 Admin template to disable Cached Exchange Mode while also having the option to select it on the client side if needed.

Once the policy is applied, it will gray out the checkbox and users cannot select Cached Exchange Mode.

Is there some sort of registry hack that can be done to enable this?

[image: cached-mode-disabled-and-grayed-out]

Answer (score 0):

Cached Exchange Mode is controlled by the following key;
[HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\\13dbb0c8aa05101a9bb000aa002fc45a]

00036601 (REG_BINARY)

enabled value: 84 01 00 00

enabled with Public Folders/Favorites: 84 05 00 00

disabled value: 04 00 00 00

Reference：https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/cachedmoderegkey.htm

Comment: If I can remember correctly, only up until Outlook 2010